# Weird operator precedence with ?? (null coalescing operator)

Tags: c#, types, null-coalescing-operator

Recently I had a weird bug where I was concatenating a string with an `int?` and then adding another string after that.

My code was basically the equivalent of this:

```
int? x=10;
string s = "foo" + x ?? 0 + "bar";
```

Amazingly enough this will run and compile without warnings or incompatible type errors, as will this:

```
int? x=10;
string s = "foo" + x ?? "0" + "bar";
```

And then this results in an unexpected type incompatibility error:

```
int? x=10;
string s = "foo" + x ?? 0 + 12;
```

As will this simpler example:

```
int? x=10;
string s = "foo" + x ?? 0;
```

Can someone explain how this works to me?

Comment: A related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218140/null-coalescing-operator-and-lambda-expression/3218268#3218268

Comment: And here is a link that does not make my answer glow... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218140/null-coalescing-operator-and-lambda-expression

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The null coalescing operator has very low [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) so your code is being interpreted as:

```
int? x = 10;
string s = ("foo" + x) ?? (0 + "bar");
```

In this example both expressions are strings so it compiles, but doesn't do what you want. In your next example the left side of the `??` operator is a string, but the right hand side is an integer so it doesn't compile:

```
int? x = 10;
string s = ("foo" + x) ?? (0 + 12);
// Error: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'
```

The solution of course is to add parentheses:

```
int? x = 10;
string s = "foo" + (x ?? 0) + "bar";
```

Comment: Ah so because of the low precedence the two sides form almost two separate expressions

Comment: this explains why `int x = 10; string s = "foo" + x ?? "0";` works then

Answer (score 11):

The `??` operator has lower [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) than the `+` operator, so your expression really works as:

```
string s = ("foo" + x) ?? (0 + "bar");
```

First the string `"foo"` and the string value of `x` are concatenated, and if that would be null (which it can't be), the string value of `0` and the string `"bar"` are concatenated.