# How to handle null if passed from a calling function to a called function whose parameter is nullable integer?

Tags: c#

I have been asked a question in the interview

```
public int Add(int? a, int? b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

null is passed in a's place. how will you handle this?

I said

```
if (a == null ) { //do something }
else { // do something }
```

He didnot say anything.

Waiting for the reply.

Comment: btw have you passed the interview or not?

Comment: great :) which company?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whtever you have said its also correct but interviewer might wanted to know how updated you are..

```
 if(!a.HasValue)
    {
        a = 0;
    }
```

or shorter is :-

```
a = a != null ? a : 0;
```

and one more operator as suggested by Askolein is [??](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) as shown below :-

```
a ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

As an interviewer I would have expected this:

```
public int Add(int? a, int? b)
{
    return (a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0);
}
```

It is called [coalescing operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) and exists in several languages and is made exactly for that purpose. It has a [very low precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259352/weird-operator-precedence-with-null-coalescing-operator) so do not forget the `( )`

Answer (score 2):

he probably wanted it to be

```
public int Add(int? a, int? b)
{
    a = a!= null ? a : 0;
    b = b!= null ? b : 0;
    return a+b;
}
```

or something of the sort, meaning you place 0 instead of `null`

Comment: More natural: `a = a ?? 0; b = b ?? 0;` It almost feels like there should exist an operator so you could say `a ??= 0`, but there does not. The type of `a` and `b` are still `Nullable<>`, so your code does not compile yet (`a+b` is `Nullable<>`, declared return type is not)!

Answer (score 2):

It's not a very good question. The code as presented doesn't compile, and the shortest possible fix is actually to change the function signature to

```
public int? Add(int? a, int? b)
```

Addition is supported on nullable integers through lifting: adding `null` to another value will just yield `null`. This is almost certainly not what the interviewer was angling for; probably they intended you to treat `null` as if it was `0`, for which `a ??  0` suffices. But maybe they wanted `(a + b) ?? 0` instead, which returns 0 if either operand is `null`.

Well, on second thought, maybe it *is* a good question, to see if you would ask follow-up questions. The most pertinent one would be: "what do you *want* this function to do when presented with `null`s?"

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the `GetValueOrDefault` method of `Nullable<T>` which will substitute the default value of `T`, which is zero for `int`, if it is `null`.

```
public int Add(int? a, int? b)
{
    return a.GetValueOrDefault() + b.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

But really you should have asked what the interviewer wanted the method to do with nulls as this could also have been valid

```
public int Add(int? a, int? b)
{
    if(!a.HasValue)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("a");
    if(!b.HasValue)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("b");
    return a.Value + b.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I learnt about [Null-Conditional Operator ( C# 6.0 )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

```
return (a?. + b?.);
```

also `return (a + b);` works fine