# null ?? coalescing operator

Tags: c#, .net

Got stumped in production code because of my bad understanding. The following code gives incorrect results

```
        double? value1 = 1;
        double intermediateVariable = 2;
        double? value2 = 0;
        double? value3 = 1;
        double? resultValue1 = value1 ?? 0 + intermediateVariable + value2 ?? 0 + value3 ?? 0;
        double? resultValue1braces = (value1 ?? 0) + intermediateVariable + (value2 ?? 0) + (value3 ?? 0);
        Console.WriteLine(resultValue1);
```

The output of the above code is "1".
If I rewrite the above addition line as below, the result is = 4.

```
         double? resultValue1braces = (value1 ?? 0) + intermediateVariable + (value2 ?? 0) + (value3 ?? 0);
        Console.WriteLine(resultValue1braces);
```

Can some one help understand why the individual ?? operator statements are not evaluated first if not included inside braces?
If I use value1 ?? 0, the next statement seems to be ignored and if I use (value1 ?? 0) the next statements are looking like evaluated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259352/weird-operator-precedence-with-null-coalescing-operator

Comment: `??` has the lowest precedence and its short circuiting, so everything to the right of `??` is only executed *if* what's left of it is null. This is just like using `&&` or `||`, where the other side is short circuited if the condition is met.