# Combining null coalescing operator with a conditional

Tags: c#

I'm trying to combine the coalescing operator with a conditional operator. This won't compile, and I'm wondering if there is a way around it without writing a bunch of if statements:

```
public static Setting GetSetting(this Account account, string key, bool newIfNull = true)
{
    return account.Settings
        .FirstOrDefault(x =>
            x.Key.Equals(key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) ??
                newIfNull ? new Setting
                {
                    Key = key
                } : null
    };
}
```

This would be the alternative with if statments:

```
public static Setting GetSetting(this Account account, string key, bool newIfNull = true)
{
    var setting = account.Settings
        .FirstOrDefault(x =>
            x.Key.Equals(key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (setting != null)
    {
        return setting;
    }

    return newIfNull ? new Setting
    {
        Key = key
    } : null;
}
```

Any suggestions? I'm also curious as to why it can't compile if anyone knows.

Comment: Add some parens? `thing ?? (cond ? t : f)`

Comment: Have you tried putting everything after `??` in brackets?

Comment: what is the logic behind?

Comment: Please show the compiler error and what you have tried to resolve it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `String.Equals` is never null so this expression makes no sense. The expression in `FirstOrDefault` must return a boolean, so returning a `Setting` or `null` makes no sense either. Were you trying tto check whether `Key` is null or equal to something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259352/weird-operator-precedence-with-null-coalescing-operator

Comment: Updated my question. I want to return a new Setting if the parameter newIfNull is true, otherwise just return null.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You parsed it wrong -- the `??` is after the `FirstOrDefault`, not after the `Equals`

Comment: @canton7 that's why formatting matters. Also explaining the problem instead of posting the attempted solution

Comment: @canton7 and putting everything in one line isn't always a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null-coalescing operator [has higher precendence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) than the ternary operator. This means that the expression:

```
thing ?? cond ? t : f
```

Gets bound as:

```
(thing ?? cond) ? t : f
```

If you want to change this, use the same tool that you use to resolve every precedence issue: parentheses.

```
thing ?? (cond ? t : f)
```

In your example:

```
public static Setting GetSetting(this Account account, string key, bool newIfNull = true)
{
    return account.Settings
        .FirstOrDefault(x =>
            x.Key.Equals(key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) ??
                (newIfNull ? new Setting
                {
                    Key = key
                } : null)
    };
}
```

Comment: The usage of parenthesis is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: (I did say that 10 mins ago in the comments...)

Comment: well I guess you get more karma for a correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A switch expression would be easier to read :

```
var setting = account.Settings
       .FirstOrDefault(x =>x.Key.Equals(key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

return setting switch {
    Setting s=>s,
    null when newIfNull =>new Setting { Key = key },
    _ => null
};
```

or

```
var setting = account.Settings
       .FirstOrDefault(x =>x.Key.Equals(key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

return (setting,newIfNull) 
    switch 
    {
        (Setting s,_)=>s,
        (_,true)  => new Setting { Key = key },
        _ => null
    };
```

This can be put in a single expression but I suspect this question alone shows that one-liners aren't always a good idea:

```
return account.Settings
       .FirstOrDefault(x =>x.Key.Equals(key, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
       switch {
           Setting s=>s,
           null when newIfNull =>new Setting { Key = key },
           _ => null
};
```

For academic purposes, the tuple form is

```
return ( newIfNull, account.Settings.FirstOrDefault(x =>x.Key.Equals(key, 
                         StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    )
    switch 
    {
        (_,Setting s)=>s,
        (true,_)  => new Setting { Key = key },
        _ => null
    };
```

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but that takes me about 5x longer to parse than the OP's version. Replacing the `_` branch with `(null, false)` would help I think, but even then

Comment: @canton7 bad copy/pasting. I wouldn't use a single expression for this in any case, the condition is too long so it's way too easy to make a mistake.