# How to Coalesce a Lambda Delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

I want to do this:

```
class Foo {

  static Func<string> sRunner;

  Func<string> _runner;

  public Foo(Func<string> runner){

    _runner = runner ?? sRunner ?? () => "Hey!";

  }
}
```

I get an "invalid expression" term on the lambda.  Can that be fixed inline?

Comment: I like this way to use the null coalescing operator :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Null-coalescing operator and lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218140/null-coalescing-operator-and-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
_runner = runner ?? sRunner ?? (() => "Hey!");
```