# How to use ?? with lambda expression?

Tags: c#

Can we simplify the following with `??` and lambda expression?

```
Func<int, int> func = f; // f is a function parameter 
if (func == null) // if f passed by the user is null then we use the default identity function f(x)=x.
    func = x => x;
```

I cannot do something `Func<int, int> func = f ?? x=>x;`. Could you?

## Edit

My scenario is as follows.

```
class Program
{
    static double Average(int[] data, Func<int, int> f = null)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        Func<int, int> func = f ?? new Func<int, int>(x => x);
        //Func<int, int> func = f;
        //if (func == null)
        //    func = x => x;
        foreach (int x in data)
            sum += func(x);

        return (double)sum / data.Length;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] data = { 1, 2, 3 };
        Console.WriteLine(Average(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting an error with your bottom line, something about not being able to determine the type of `x=>x`.

Have you tried constructing the func explicitly, such as: `var func = f ?? new Func<int, int>(x => x);`

Comment: Is my question clear enough? I leave now and will return tomorrow.

Comment: [Func<int, int> func f ?? (x => x);](https://ideone.com/9knHTC)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It can be null in the case if `f` is a parameter of a method and null is passed to it.

Comment: @E.Moffat: Your answer is correct. `var func = f ?? new Func<int, int>(x => x);` works. Thank you very much. If you want to submit as an answer, please do. Or I will delete this question tomorrow. Thank you all and bye.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null-coalescing operator and lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218140/null-coalescing-operator-and-lambda-expression)

Comment: @CrazyFrog if `var func = f ?? (x => x);` works, as others have commented, I'd use that instead since it looks a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The precedence of null-coalescing operator is higher than lambda declaration.

```
Func<int, int> func = f ?? (x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Null-coalescing operator and lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218140/null-coalescing-operator-and-lambda-expression)

This should work

```
Func<int, int> func = f ?? (x=>x);
```

Your statement is parsed as

```
Func<int, int> func = (f ?? x)=>x;
```

Please search through the available answers first to check if somebody has already answered it.